# Pass selected value in dropdownlist from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a little problem, I have to pass the parameter from the view to controller, I succes to do it with the input field, but with @ html.dropdownList I don't know how I should do it, can you please help me here is my code:

view :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetFilterList", "Inconsistencies",
new AjaxOptions
{
HttpMethod = "POST",
UpdateTargetId = "refreshList",
}, new { @id = "FileList" }
))
{


<span class="input-group-addon">Date de début</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="jj/mm/aaaa" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" />

<span class="input-group-addon">Date de fin</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="jj/mm/aaaa" id="EnDate" name="EnDate" />

<span class="input-group-addon">Etat inco</span>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Inconsistences.InconsistencyStateId, Model.StateList, new { id = "state", }) //how to pass the selected value to controller ?

<span class="input-group-addon">Type inco</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="type" name="type" />


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm fsc-btn-1" id="search">
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
<span>Recherche</span>
</button>


}
```

controller :

```
   [HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetFilterList(DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EnDate, decimal? State, decimal? type)
{
InconsistenciesModel model = new InconsistenciesModel();

model.FillDDL();
model.GetListFilter(StartDate, EnDate,State, type);
return PartialView("_InconsistenciesList", model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simplify you Ajax.BeginForm as

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetFilterList", "Inconsistencies")
    {
        .......    
    }
```

This search button's action will post all the form values including your dropdown's selected value to controller.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It may help you to know how **any** values get passed to a controller.

```
<form>
  <input name="someValue" type="text" value="test" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</submit>
</form>
```

Using the standard *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* scheme, a value of `someValue=test` will be send to the server.

You *could* access the value directly using the standard Request api in ASP.net.

```
 public ActionResult Test(){

      string someValue = Request.Form("someValue");
 }
```

The MVC frameworks adds some nice features by automatically binding Form and Querystring, and Route parameters values to MVC action parameters.

```
 public ActionResult Test(string someValue){

 }
```

The Framework also has features for Binding to complex types as well (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx).

In your case, the `m=> m.Inconsistences.InconsistencyStateId` most likely gets translated into the name "Inconsistences_InconsistencyStateId"

```
 public ActionResult GetFilterList(string Inconsistences_InconsistencyStateId){

 }

 or 

 // MVC will try to convert the value into an integer
 public ActionResult GetFilterList(int Inconsistences_InconsistencyStateId){

 }

 // MVC will throw an error if the parameter is missing, so you may need to make any ValueType parameters nullable.
 public ActionResult GetFilterList(int? Inconsistences_InconsistencyStateId){

 }
```

or you can you automatic Model binding

```
public class Inconsistences {
 public int InconsistencyStateId {get;set;}
}

public class InconsistenciesModel {
   public Inconsistences Inconsistences {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult GetFilterList(InconsistenciesModel model) {

    int id = model.Inconsistences.InconsistencyStateId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change your dropdown to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Inconsistences.InconsistencyStateId, Model.StateList, new { name = "state", })
```

OR

if `m=> m.Inconsistences.InconsistencyStateId` mostly gets rendered into the name attribute "`Inconsistences_InconsistencyStateId`", then use as below 
in controller. Or please check dropdown name attribute in your rendered html and change action parameter accordingly.

```
public ActionResult GetFilterList(DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EnDate, decimal? State, int Inconsistences_InconsistencyStateId)
{
     ...
}
```

This will work. Because form post is based on the name value pair inside the form.